# Assigning & Calculating Values Using PHP via an HTML Form

Tags: php, html

I am new to programming and I am in need of of assistance. I have a HTML form on a page called addbooking.php with the following code:

```
<form method = "post" action = "" > 
       <table cellspacing="15">

<tr>
  <th>Bookingid </th>
  <td><input type = "text" name = "bookingid"/> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Booking Name </th>
  <td><input type = "text" name = "bookingname" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th> <label for = "Cabin Type">Cabin Type </label> </th>
   td><select name = "Cabin Type" id = "Cabin Type">
   <option select>Select a Cabin Type</option>
   <option value = "Luxury Cabin">Luxury Cabin </option>
   <option value = "Contemporary Cabin">Contemporary Cabin  </option>
   <option value = "Original Cabin">Original Cabin </option>
   </select>
   </td>
   </tr>

<tr>
  <th>Length of Stay </th>
  <td><input type = "text" name = "lengthofstay" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Details About Guests </th>
  <td><textarea cols = "30" rows = "5" type = "text" name="guests_description" 
   /> </textarea> </td>
</tr> 

<tr>
   <th>Booking Start Date </th>
   <td><input type = "text" name = "startdate" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <th>Booking End Date </th>
   <td><input type = "text" name = "enddate" /> </td>
</tr>   

<tr>
   <th>Other Relavant Information </th>
   <td><textarea cols = "30" rows = "5" type = "text" name="other_information"  
   /> </textarea> </td>
</tr>        

<tr>
  <th> </th>
  <td> <input type = "submit" value = "Create Booking!" name = 
       "bookingdetails" /> </td>
</tr> 
</table>             
</form>
```

I also have php code on the same page which looks like the following:

```
<?php                         
   include ('dbconnect.php');  

// get values from the form
     function getPosts(){
     $posts = array();
     $posts[0] = $_POST['bookingid'];
     $posts[1] = $_POST['bookingname'];
     $posts[2] = $_POST['lengthofstay'];
     $posts[3] = $_POST['guests_description'];       
     $posts[4] = $_POST['startdate'];
     $posts[5] = $_POST['enddate'];
     $posts[6] = $_POST['other_information'];
     return $posts;
    } 

 if (isset($_POST['bookingdetails'])) {  

  $data = getPosts();


 if (empty($bookingname)){
        $errors[] = "Please enter the your booking name.";
    }

 if(empty($errors)){
        foreach($errors as $error){
            echo $error . "<br/>";
    }
 else{

  $insert_Query = "insert into bookings 
    (Bookingid,Bookingname,Lengthofstay,Details_about_guests,
     Booking_start_date,Booking_end_date,Other_relavant_information)
     values ('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]',
     '$data[5]','$data[6]')";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $insert_Query);

 if ($result)
 {
 echo "<font color = 'green' . <p>Successfully Booked</p> </font>";
 }
 else{
   echo "<p> Something went Wrong </p>" . mysqli_error ($db);

    }
   }
  }
  ?>
```

I also have a table in my database called cabins which looks like:

[image: Picture of the Cabins table]

Now, what I need some assistance with is how do I assign each of the prices from the Cabin_Price column to each item in the drop down menu on the form and then when the "booking details" button is pressed multiply the chosen value/option for e.g '1200' by what ever value is entered in the 'Length of Stay' field for e.g '4' using php. Below is a picture of what I mean:

[image: Assigning the Values to Each Cabin Type]

Comment: Put the cabin ID into `value` of the `<option>`. Then when the form is submitted, look up the price for that cabin ID in the database.

Comment: Can you use `<option value = "1200">Luxury Cabin </option>` instead of `<option value = "Luxury Cabin">Luxury Cabin </option>` ? So you can get the exact value. Since value can be represents as the `price`, you can put the value there.

Comment: @Hash Putting the price into the form is a very bad idea. The user can modify the form in Developer Tools and change the prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your menu so that the values of the options are the cabin ID. Then when you're processing the form, you look up the price, and multiply by the length of stay. So the menu should look like:

```
<select name = "Cabin Type" id = "Cabin Type">
    <option select>Select a Cabin Type</option>
    <option value = "1">Luxury Cabin </option>
    <option value = "2">Contemporary Cabin  </option>
    <option value = "3">Original Cabin </option>
</select>
```

And when the form is submitted, you do a query like:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT cabin_price FROM cabins WHERE cabin_id = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $_POST["Cabin Type"]);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$price = $row['cabin_price'];
$total_price = $price * $_POST['lengthofstay'];
```

Comment: hey, when I use the code I am getting PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function prepare

Comment: The above code assumes you're using PDO. If you're using some other MySQL extension you'll have to convert to that. It's just a demonstration of the general idea.

Comment: You added your mysqli code after I posted my answer. Your code is subject to SQL injection, you should learn how to do prepared statements.